# Windows Expression Encoder ScreenCaptureJob Issue

Tags: c#, screen-capture, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk, expression-encoder-4

Well, it's quite simple. When I try to create a new `ScreenCaptureJob`:

```
job = new ScreenCaptureJob();
```

It says that the name 'job' does not exist in the current context.

I have imported `Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.ScreenCapture` so I don't know what it could be.

If anyone has any ideas, that would be great.

Comment: If compiles says you that, then you probably just forgot to define a field `job` in your class

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten to do ScreenCaptureJob job; at the top. I thought I was going insane. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write:

```
ScreenCaptureJob job = new ScreenCaptureJob();
```